Flow Custom Metadata in Entry Conditions causes Problems on Lead Convertion
We have a Custom Metadata called Flow Setting where we can enable and disable based on the Object the Update or Creation. Previously we had no Entry Conditions for the Account Flow and inside the Account Flow I had a Get Record to get the Record based on the Operation and Object. If it's active, I'm doing some Updates to the Account, otherwise it shouldn't run. Now you can directly access the Custom Metadata in the Entry Condition and therefore I have updated my Flow. This looks now like this:

This is working fine. But I also have a Lead Convertion in place which uses the Apex Method
Database.convertLead(leadsToConvert, false);
With the Adjustments described above I'm getting the following Error Message:
There was an error converting the lead. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact your administrator.
When I activate the old Flow Version where I get the Custom Metadata with a Get Record, everything is working fine.

You might try moving the entry condition into a decision node (first element of flow)

If you read my Question you might saw that I came from this Solution and wanted to migrate to do the Decision directly in the Entry Condition.

my suggestion was to avoid the Get Records and just use the CMDT value directly in the decision element; I can't explain the reason for why it doesn't work in the entry conditions and would contact SFDC Support if you have it

Ok, that would work but with this the Flow always Start which I want to avoid with the new Approach. This would give us the Option to disable the Operation in the Metadata if we are doing mass Updates and we don't want to trigger the Flow for it.

ah, the way I disable flows in metadata is to use a running user that has a custom permission Automation_Disabled assigned.  This can be checked in the entry condition.  You can also use hierarchical custom settings (assigned to the running user). These too can be checked in entry conditions
